# What scanner should I buy to scan a big stack of photos?

Tags: photos, scanner

I want to scan a huge pile of photos (10,000+).

What hardware/software can I use to automatically feed and scan these photos?

Requirements

- The photos are 4 ¼” x 6”
- No excessive bending of the photos

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: Ended up buying 6 ScanSnap S1500, http://www.fujitsu.ca/products/scansnap/s1500/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into outsourcing your work to a company that specializes in photo scanning.

MacWorld had [an article in October 2009](http://www.macworld.com/article/143504/2009/10/outsourcescanning.html) reviewing 3 online scanning services:

> I placed orders with these three
>   scanning companies: [ScanDigital.com](http://www.scandigital.com),
>   [DigMyPics.com](http://www.digmypics.com), and [ScanCafe.com](http://www.scancafe.com). All
>   three services have similar approaches
>   to customer service, and each
>   successfully completed the orders I
>   placed, delivering scans and returning
>   the original materials to me in good
>   condition. However, the services did
>   have varying strengths and weaknesses
>   in the following  areas: placing the
>   order, ongoing communication,
>   turnaround time, scan and retouching
>   quality, after-order support, and
>   pricing.
>
> [...]
>
> For ease of use and fast turnaround
>   time, it's hard to beat
>   ScanDigital.com, especially if you're
>   archiving 35mm slides. They
>   communicate well, provide free online
>   storage of your images, and generally
>   produce good output results. DigMyPics
>   is also a strong contender, especially
>   if you have lots of prints to scan,
>   and you want to review the results
>   online before making a final decision.
>   But if you want the best scans and are
>   willing to wait for them, then
>   ScanCafe is my recommended choice.
>
> You may even be lucky enough to have a
>   local scanning service that you can
>   work with face to face. That would
>   certainly simplify using an outside
>   vendor and help easy any anxiety you
>   have about sending off one-of-a-kind
>   photographs. So be sure to also look
>   around locally when contemplating
>   options.

I also found a few recommendations online for [ScanMyPhotos.com](http://www.scanmyphotos.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have 10,000+, you really have two choices and it is up to you:

1. Get a multifunction device and simply get started - it will take ages, but the cheapest solution, typically the scan quality is very good but you can usually change/choose.
2. Get an office-class scanner with an autofeeder [such as this one](http://www.epson.co.uk/Scanners/Epson-GT-2500) (Just an example, You will have to compare yourself specification and features). Getting something like this will be a lot more expensive, but will cut down the time greatly. (Even if you just look at scanning speed, remember that you will probably not be waiting next to it - it takes time to go to the scanner, change page, line up e.t.c.)

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer! I forgot one important requirement: no bending of the photos as depicted in the epson GT 2500

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know any that don't bend at all - you will have to compare/ring manufacturers and ask... You may be best off buying 2-3 of the cheapest all in ones (just a cheap one with good resolution - the scanners are usually of similar specification and you will not be using the printer) and simply getting on with it... It will be a hard and annoying job, but the quicker you start,(and the more you can do at once!) the quicker you finish!

Comment: just to clarify it the photos can bend a bit, they just can't take the 180 turn, like the epson gt 2500